# JSONObject parsing in android?

Tags: android, json, jsonparser

The JSONObject looks like

```
{"result":
     {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"ankur",
        "email":"ankur@gmail.com",
        "address":"bblock",
        "designation":"devloper",
        "department":"development",
        "balanceleave":"5"
     }
}
```

and my parse code looks like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Profile.class);
intent.putExtra("id", response.getString("id"));
intent.putExtra("name", response.getString("name"));
intent.putExtra("email", response.getString("email"));
intent.putExtra("address", response.getString("address"));
intent.putExtra("designation", response.getString("designation"));
intent.putExtra("department", response.getString("department"));
intent.putExtra("balanceleave", response.getString("balanceleave"));

startActivity(intent);
```

Can you help me out, actually I am parsing the JSON and sending it to the profile activity to display and if you can comeup with something that I can send the JSONObject to profile that would be great!!

Comment: What's the exact problem? You'll need to parse it somewhere right? Recommendation: Use Gson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

```
JSONObject response=new JSONObject("your response string");
JSONObject result=response.getJSONObject("result");
String id=result.getString("id");
String name=result.getString("name"));
String email=result.getString("email"));
String address=result..getString("address"));
String designation=result.getString("designation"));
String department=result.getString("department"));
String balanceleave=result.getString("balanceleave"));
```

Comment: Thanks bro you answered my second upcoming question.

Comment: Welcome @YashKumarAtri

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to convert `JsonObject` to `String` and then send via `Bundle` to Profile Screen. Like below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Profile.class);
intent.putExtra("JSON_OBJECT", response.toString());


                                startActivity(intent);
```

To Get that

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String json = i.getStringExtra("JSON_OBJECT");
try{
JsonObject json = new JsonObject(json);
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write below line

```
JSONString url = objectname.getJsonString("url");
```

then put in intent

Comment: There is no url in the question